# To retrieve contact list with number in android

Tags: android, android-contacts

Hi i want to retrieve name and numbers from contact list in android ,am using following code, it will give me name but not number it gives null value  for number

**NOTE**: am using android emulator

```
  public void demo(){
    String phoneNumber;
    String [] item = new String[]{ People._ID,

            People.NAME,
            People.NUMBER};

    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI ,item , null, null, null);
    int phoneNumberIndex = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NUMBER);
    if (cur != null) {
        Log.v("cur not null", "Cursor Not null");

        if (cur.moveToNext()) {
            Log.v("moveToNext", "Moved to first");
            Log.v("moveToNext", "Cursor Moved to first and checking");
            phoneNumber = cur.getString(phoneNumberIndex);
            System.out.println("****** from_number "+phoneNumber +" *****************");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It gives null because u r trying to retrieve only one number.. this should work..

```
if (cur.moveToNext()) {
            Log.v("moveToNext", "Moved to first");
            Log.v("moveToNext", "Cursor Moved to first and checking");
while(cur.moveToNext())
{
            phoneNumber = cur.getString(phoneNumberIndex);
            System.out.println("****** from_number "+phoneNumber +" *****************");
}
        }
```